# How to display multiple rows in macos menubar app?

Tags: swift, macos, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

Originally I thought adding new line should work. The problem is, the line height is too big. How can I make it more dense(closer to each other)?

There's the following [example on git](https://github.com/Tao93/NetTool/blob/3211169ac058c0edf0b13fca9dd5777f052d5f5c/NeTool/StatusBarView.swift) starting line 41. But apple docs say that custom view inside of NSStatusItem is deprecated. (not sure if it's deprecated for views inside of NSMenuItem)

```
        let statusBar = NSStatusBar.system
        statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)
        statusBarItem.button?.title = "123\n456"
```

**UPD**
What I got so far. It's not Y centred though. And `statusItem?.button?.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: -2.0, ...` seems incorrect and shifts the leading icon to the bottom.

```
var comb = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: str1)
comb.append(br) // new line
comb.append(str2)
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 9

comb.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, comb.length))
statusItem?.button?.attributedTitle = comb
```

**UPD** (retarted approach with \n and baselineoffset)

```
var comb = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: NSAttributedString(string: "\n")) // this
comb.append(top)
comb.append(br)
comb.append(bottom)

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 9
comb.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset, value: 3.0, range:NSMakeRange(0, comb.length))
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `title`, set the `attributeTitle` to an attributed string with a paragraph style with a smaller line-height value.

Answer (score 1):

As matt noted, use `attributeTitle` and `NSMutableParagraph`

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 9
paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
```

Columns formatting can be achieved by using tabs, spaces, or other separators

```
NSAttributedString(string: "\n10 \u{2022} 220 \u{2022} 4999", attributes: textAttr) // this is a row
```

`statusItem?.button?.attributedTitle = rows`

And to shift text from the bottom:

```
rows.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset, value: 2.0, range:NSMakeRange(0, rows.length))
```

[image]